# how to convert string date to UTC date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a date string like this: `"2010-07-12T00:00:00"`, 
I would like to convert this date string to UTC format.
how do I convert this string date(`"2010-07-12T00:00:00"`) to UTC date format?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you looking for a specific format, or are you trying to convert between time zones? Will this do: `new Date("2010-07-12T00:00:00").toUTCString()` ?

Comment: UTC is a standard, not a format. The string is in an ISO 8601 format. As has no time zone, it will represent a different moment in time depending on the time zone assumed in conversion (whether the assumed time zone is UTC/GMT or any other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
new Date("2010-07-12T00:00:00").toUTCString();
```

Comment: No, not like that. The string may be parsed as UTC, local or an invalid date by browsers in use.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    var d = new Date("2010-07-12T00:00:00");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```